# Limiting # of dropdownmenu items to view

Tags: delphi, drop-down-menu, toolbar

I use a TToolButton with a DropDownMenu to which I assigned a PopupMenu. When I click the toolbutton ALL menu items are shown, even when there are 50 or more. Is there a way to limit the number of visible menuitems and scroll thu them like in a TComboBox?

Comment: A (standard Windows) *popup menu* can never be scrolled using a scroll bar. What I am saying is: are you sure a (standard Windows) popup menu is the right control for the task?

Comment: Either organise items into submenus or [break](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Menus.TMenuItem.Break) menu into multiple columns.

Comment: If you have a popup menu with that many items, you're doing something wrong. You should break the menu up into categories, and create submenus under those categories. You should also think about the poor user who has to use the menu, and maybe break the functionality out into multiple toolbuttons with smaller menus per button.

Comment: I would use toolbar 2000 with sptbx.

Comment: I understand your questioning my choice of a Popup for so many items. I am sorry indeed for the poor user, but imho the user is not the less poorer by using a combobox. I do have a reason using a popup, hence the question of scrolling. I once saw a menu with an arrow up and down, but can't remember where. The material (being musical scales) does not lend itself well for categorizing, but I did not know about multi-column menu's. I'll try that and else maybe off to comboboxes. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: @ain, The break property works great! Thanks for the suggestion.